# Email regex not working

Tags: regex

I found this regex:

```
^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

but I have 2 problems with it:

1. I can't enter a single letter domain - like: a@a.me
2. I can enter slashback \ which is not valid

Can you help fixing this?

Comment: @Necreaux - might be possible, but I'm still interested in knowing why [\w\.-] only allows 1 character (I'm a regex noob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\w[\w\.-]+` reads *"a alphanum char followed by **one or more** alphanumchar, dot or dash"*. You thus need `\w[\w\.-]*`: *"a alphanum char followed by **zero or more** alphanumchar, dot or dash"*.
2. `[^\s()<>@,;:\/]` lists all the chars that are not allowed: `\s()<>@,;:/` (`\/` is actually an escaped `/`). You thus need to add the (escaped) backslash: `[^\s()<>@,;:\/\\]`.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something today :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\s()<>@,;:\/\\]+@\w([\w\.-]+)?\.[a-z]{2,}$
```